# PHP Table from results

Tags: php

I am trying to nicely format some results but am unsure how best to approach it..

My result sets look like this:

```
2013-05 Registrations = 379
Players = 270
Minutes = 52734
Average = 195
Registered & Logged In Month 1 = 323
Retained Month 2 = 43%
Retained Month 3 = 23%
Retained Month 4 = 17%
Retained Month 5 = 12%
Retained Month 6 = 9%
Retained Month 7 = 8%
Retained Month 8 = 7%
Retained Month 9 = 7%
Retained Month 10 = 6%
Retained Month 11 = 6%
Retained Month 12 = 5%
```

And then repeat for the next month....

Ideally I'd like to put these into a table with the year / month as a column heading and the players minutes etc as line identifiers.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you only have this string, or is there another source for this data?

Comment: How are the results currently stored, is it an array? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Perhaps a pivot table would be helpful.

Comment: Your question is unclear, provide some more details.

Comment: How did you get that output??? sorry dude we cant read your mind. Provide more info.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear.

The above results are displayed one at a time from a series of MySQL queries. I loop through those MySQL queries to get 12 months worth of data....

I then loop the whole process for every month between two dates... so I could generate 12 sets of the above data for a 1 year period.

I am sure I could store the data above in an array for each month, but I am unsure the best way to organise it and then print it in a nice table... which is dynamic enough to display from 1 - 12 sets..

I hope that makes sense.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

First echo your beginning table tags, with headers, then iterate over your results, echoing table rows with the content.  Then, outside your `while loop` (or whatever you use), add the closing table tags.